# The reference to entity "appId" must end with the ';' delimiter. blogger error

Tags: jquery, blogger

I am trying to use this script in blogger template for enable comprassion of facebook like box . but when i try to paste this code above ( as i cannot find  tag) . and click on save this error come in red . can someone correct what I am missing . also is this code will really effect  on my page speed ? ref for the code is http://hayageek.com/jquery-lazy-loading-scripts/
 and the code is

```
**in head section:**
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

**in body section:**

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        type: "scroll",
        scripts: [
        "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js",
        "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=445577382175430",
        "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"
            ],
        success: function () {
             FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        }
    };
    $.lazyscript(options);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted your code for blogger compatibility, use the below script and it will not show any error:

```
&lt;script&gt;
$undefineddocument).readyundefinedfunction undefined) {
    var options = {
        type: &quot;scroll&quot;,
        scripts: [
        &quot;http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js&quot;,
        &quot;http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=445577382175430&quot;,
        &quot;https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js&quot;
            ],
        success: function undefined) {
             FB.initundefined{ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        }
    };
    $.lazyscriptundefinedoptions);

});
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Comment: thank you so much sir. Now it is saved without any errors in blogger template.. you are genious brother..I have one more question sir ,  does this code will really effect on page speed by enabling compression ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `amp;`   to  `1&appld`

It will be

```
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=445577382175430
```